# Display String and number together in tableview

Tags: iphone

I am trying to concatenate and display string and number together in a table view cell. Is there any mechanism to convert both of them together to a label string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: @d",strIntName, [num intValue]];

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSString * compositeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %d", myOtherString, myInt]`

Answer (score 1):

This is described in `NSString stringWithFormat:` in the NSString documentation.

Answer (score 0):

cell.textLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",yourString,yourNumber];